# Shell not picking correct path to run drush

Tags: sh, homebrew, drush

I've got drush in `/usr/local/bin`. Running `which drush` returns `/usr/local/bin/drush`. However running `drush` displays "`-bash: /usr/bin/drush: No such file or directory`". Running `/usr/local/bin/drush` works correctly.

My $PATH is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin`

[added in an edit] Before I had this issue I removed a copy of the script that *was* at `/usr/bin/drush`. It wasn't built correctly.

What on earth could be causing this problem? I do not want to have to type out `/usr/local/bin/drush` every time; that's why `/usr/local/bin` is in my `$PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you run `drush` before in this shell, then moved it from `/usr/bin` to `/usr/local/bin` ? If so, the `hash` command will show that the shell has remembered the command in the `/usr/bin` location and will presume it's there without re-checking. Run `hash -r` will clear this list.

Worked example:

```
$ echo >/usr/bin/hello 'echo hello'
$ chmod +x /usr/bin/hello
$ hash
hits    command
   1    /bin/chmod
$ hello
hello
$ hash
hits    command
   1    /bin/chmod
   1    /usr/bin/hello
$ which hello
/usr/bin/hello
$ mv /usr/bin/hello /usr/local/bin/
$ hello
bash: /usr/bin/hello: No such file or directory
$ hash
hits    command
   1    /usr/bin/which
   1    /bin/chmod
   1    /bin/mv
   2    /usr/bin/hello
$ which hello
/usr/local/bin/hello
$ hash -r
$ hash
hash: hash table empty
$ hello
hello
$ hash
hits    command
   1    /usr/local/bin/hello
```

Comment: I think this may be my problem, but `hash -d` only shows me a list. It doesn't seem to be clearing anything.

Comment: sorry, I meant `hash -r`

Comment: Excellent, that worked! So does opening another terminal for that matter, which I would have done sooner if I wasn't totally flummoxed by the problem I was having.

Comment: For the record, `hash -r drush` would rehash just this one command, which is obviously a lighter operation.